# Setting offset listener to CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport

I'm trying to set an offset listenter to CollapsingToolbarLayout to animate other objects in a synchronized way while user scrolls down or up. Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your toolbar is a direct child of AppBarLayout, you can add an AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener on the AppBarLayout.